# How to implement cascade deleting in SQLAlchemy Oracle?

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

I'm doing an API service and trying to do cascade deleting for Attachments class. All the time I get integiry error ((cx_Oracle.IntegrityError) ORA-02292:)when trying to delete a post. I've tried backref/back_populates, played with cascade='all, delete-orphan' etc - the same error. DB is Oracle. Output from `insp.get_foreign_keys("crm_post_attachments")` is:

```
[{'name': 'sys_c00310238', 'constrained_columns': ['post_id'], 'referred_schema': None, 'referred_table': 'crm_post', 'referred_columns': ['id'], 'options': {}}]
```

Here are the current models:

```
class Post(Base):
__tablename__ = "crm_post"

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
title = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
text = Column(String)
img = Column(LargeBinary)
author_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("crm_user.id"), nullable=False)
sdate = Column(DateTime)
edate = Column(DateTime)
post_type = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("crm_dir_post_types.id"), nullable=False)
attachments = relationship("PostAttachments", back_populates="post", passive_deletes=True, cascade='all, delete-orphan')


class PostAttachments(Base):
    __tablename__ = "crm_post_attachments"

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
attachment = Column(LargeBinary)
post_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("crm_post.id", ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
post = relationship("Post", back_populates="attachments", passive_deletes=True)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the exact error message(s) you receive.

Comment: Okay, that helps a bit. Now [edit] your question again to show the output from [this code](https://pastebin.com/hSumpnxZ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output from `insp.get_foreign_keys("crm_post_attachments")` shows that the actual table in the database does not match your ORM model. The model specifies

```py
    post_id = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey("crm_post.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False
    )
```

but the reflected Foreign Key from the table shows

```
[
    {
        'name': 'sys_c00310238', 
        'constrained_columns': ['post_id'], 
        'referred_schema': None, 
        'referred_table': 'crm_post', 
        'referred_columns': ['id'], 
        'options': {}
    }
]
```

The empty `options` dict indicates that no cascade rule is in effect. `passive_deletes=True` is telling SQLAlchemy not to bother taking care of cascading the deletes because the backend will handle it.

In order to match your model the FK in the table should have `'options': {'ondelete': 'CASCADE'}`. If you drop the FK and re-create it with that option, i.e.,

```sql
ALTER TABLE crm_post_attachments 
  ADD FOREIGN KEY(post_id) REFERENCES crm_post (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

then your code (with `passive_deletes=True`) should work.

Comment: By some reason when I tried to drop FK with `ALTER TABLE crm_post_attachments drop CONSTRAINT post_id` I got error _(cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-02443_ saying there is no such a constraint. So I tried to add a constraint without dropping with `ALTER TABLE crm_post_attachments ADD FOREIGN KEY(post_id) REFERENCES crm_post (id) ON DELETE CASCADE` and got another error _(cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-02275_ saying such a refferal constraint is already in the table. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `ALTER TABLE crm_post_attachments drop CONSTRAINT sys_c00310238`